# how to change the output of wp_nav_menu using css classes

Tags: menus

When we add a class to a menu item through dashboard, the css class is added to "li" tag of that item. Is there a way to add these css classes to "a" tag of that item, instead of "li" tag?

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to have this effect :

```
<li id="menu-item-290">
    <a  class="my-class" href="http://localhost/en-wptuts/">home</a>
</li>
```

instead of this one:

```
<li id="menu-item-290" class="my-class">
    <a href="http://localhost/en-wptuts/">home</a>
</li>
```

So is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you not change your CSS selector from `.my-class` to `.my-class > a`?

Comment: I'm actually trying to add font-awesome icons to my anchor elements using dashboard css custom class box and unfortunately that box, adds icons to li tag and not to a tags.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three  approaches:

### I - Plugin for the `a-class-` prefix:

We can target the `<a>` tags with the `a-class-...` class prefix.

So in your case the way to get:

```
<li id="menu-item-290" class="blue yellow ...">
    <a class="red pink" href="http://localhost/en-wptuts/">home</a>
</li>
```

is to use the following menu classes:

```
blue yellow a-class-red a-class-pink
```

We support this with the following plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Menu Link Classes (I)
 * Description: Target menu link classes with the "a-class-" class prefix.
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190844/26350
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

/**
 * Remove menu classes with the "a-class-" prefix
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function( $classes )
{
    return array_filter( 
        $classes, 
        function( $val )
        {
            return 'a-class-' !== substr( $val, 0, strlen( 'a-class-' ) );
        } 
    );
} );

/**
 * Add only "a-class-" prefixed classes to the menu link attribute
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item )
{
    if( isset( $item->classes ) )
    {
        $atts['class'] = str_replace( 
            'a-class-',
            '',
            join( 
                ' ', 
                array_filter(
                    $item->classes, 
                    function( $val )
                    {
                        return 'a-class-' === substr( $val, 0, strlen( 'a-class-' ) );
                    } 
                ) 
            )
        );
    }
    return $atts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### II - Plugin for the `li-class-` prefix:

We can also use the `li-class-...` class prefix to target the `<li>` tags instead.

So in your case the way to get:

```
<li id="menu-item-290" class="blue yellow">
    <a class="red pink" href="http://localhost/en-wptuts/">home</a>
</li>
```

is to use the following menu classes:

```
li-class-blue li-class-yellow red pink
```

Note that this will move `<li>` classes to `<a>` that do not have this prefix.

Here's the plugin to support this:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: Menu Link Classes (II) 
 * Description: Add classes prefixed with "li-class-" to the li tag, else add it to the a tag.
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190844/26350
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

/**
 * Only allow li classess that are prefixed with "li-class-"
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function( $classes )
{
    $newclasses = [];
    foreach( (array) $classes as $class )
    {
        if( 'li-class-' === substr( $class, 0, strlen( 'li-class-' ) ) )
            $newclasses[] = str_replace( 'li-class-', '', $class );
    }
    return $newclasses;

} );

/**
 * Add all classess that aren't prefixed with "a-class-" to the <a> tag
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item )
{
    if( isset( $item->classes ) )
    {
        $atts['class'] = join( 
            ' ', 
            array_filter(
                $item->classes, 
                function( $val )
                {
                    return 'li-class-' !== substr( $val, 0, strlen( 'li-class-' ) );
                } 
            ) 
        );
    }
    return $atts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### III - Plugin that moves all optional classes to the `<a>` tag:

If we use the following optional CSS classes:

```
blue yellow red pink
```

then all will be moved to the `<a>` tag:

```
<li id="menu-item-290" class="...">
    <a class="blue yellow red pink" href="http://localhost/en-wptuts/">home</a>
</li>
```

Note that non-optional classes in `<li>` are not moved to `<a>`, so that's why we keep the `...` notation in the HTML example above.

Support by the following plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Menu Link Classes (III)
 * Description: Move all optional classes from the li tag to the a tag.
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190844/26350
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

/**
 * Only allow li classess that are prefixed with "li-class-"
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function( $classes, $item )
{
    return array_filter( $classes, function( $val ) use ( $item )
    {
        return ! in_array( $val, (array) $item->wpse_classes ) ;
    } );
}, 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items',  function( $items, $menu, $args )
{
    foreach( $items as $item )
        $item->wpse_classes = $item->classes;

    return $items;
}, 10, 3 );

/**
 * Add all classess that aren't prefixed with "a-class-" to the <a> tag
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item )
{
    if( isset( $item->wpse_classes ) )
    {
        $atts['class'] = join( 
            ' ', 
            array_filter(
                $item->wpse_classes, 
                function( $val )
                {
                    return 'li-class-' !== substr( $val, 0, strlen( 'li-class-' ) );
                } 
            ) 
        );
    }
    return $atts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is what I wanted. I want to move a class that is specified in dashboard custom css menu class to the anchor tag (instead of li tag). So let's say the admin goes to dashboard and adds a css class to an item and that class is a font-awesome icon (like fa fa-pinterest-p). I want this icon to be added to anchor element of that item and not the li element of that item.

Comment: So you don't want to move an optional CSS class from the `<li>` tag to the `<a>` tag ? That's what the plugin does. Didn't know you were trying to use font-awesome, but With the above solution you would use `a-class-fa a-class-fa-pinterest` to target the `<a>` tag. Note that the plugin removes the `a-class-` prefix before it's printed to the class attribute in the `<a>` tag, so it would display as `fa fa-pinterest` @pershianix

Comment: Thank you. you're solution is great for situations that I know exactly what font icon I want to use, but I'm looking for a way to just paste a font-awesome icon class to the custom css class field and that class goes to anchor tags.

Comment: ok, most likely I'm misunderstanding your explanation regarding the setup ;-) One can paste any class into the custom css field, we just have to prefix it to control where it will show up: `<li>` or `<a>`. We could also do this vice-versa (with a little bit of code modification) to use a `li-class-` prefix instead of the `a-class-` prefix. Then we will only have to prefix classes that go into the `<li>` tag and the rest of the classes would show up in the `<a>` tag.  @pershianix

Comment: Thank you. I think with a custom walker it would be easier but I'm not good at working with walker class. could you help me with that?

Comment: ... but I don't think it's necessary to use a custom walker for this, since we have access to the `nav_menu_css_class` and `nav_menu_link_attributes` filters. Maybe you could explain it better in your question, why you can't use these filters for your setup? @pershianix

Comment: I tested your plugin and it works great but with prefixes! As I mentioned I want to just copy and paste the font icon class into the custom css class field and voila! I've solved my problem using css but I want it to be through PHP not css. Thank you again. I'm still looking for help.

Comment: I updated the answer with a second approach, where classes for the `<a>` tag are without prefix but classes for `<li>` are using the `li-class-` prefix. @pershianix

Comment: ... added the third approach as well. @pershianix

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter ( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'so_37823371_menu_item_class', 10, 4 );

function so_37823371_menu_item_class ( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ){
  $classes[] = 'nav-item';

  return $classes;
}
function add_link_atts($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = "nav-link";
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_link_atts');
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?